# Can a scenario have multiple example tables?

Tags: bdd, specflow, gherkin

I would like to write a gherkin scenario that specifies a table of parameters but represents a test for every combination of values in the table.

For example:

```
Given I visit <site>
When I enter <search_str>
Then I see at least 1 result

Examples:
| site           | search_str     |
| google.com     | pierce brosnan |
| jeeves.com     | matt leblank   |
| duckduckgo.com | jeff goldblum  |
```

I would like every **search_str** to be used on every **site**, making a total of 9 tests - not 3 tests.

How should I define this scenario?
Can multiple example tables be used per scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is no support for multi-dimensional examples tables in Gherkin scenarios as you have described. Also keep in mind what BDD is largely for: being readable to the business. We developers have to be careful not to get too technical in the feature files ;)

That being said, I can think of a couple ways to solve this problem.

1.Write either the site or the search_str multiple times like:

```
Examples:  
| site           | search_str     |  
| google.com     | pierce brosnan |  
| google.com     | matt leblank   |  
| google.com     | jeff goldblum  |  
| jeeves.com     | matt leblank   |  

etc...
```

2.Write the gherkin separately for each site like:

```
Given I visit "google.com"  
When I enter <search_str>
Then I see at least 1 result  
Examples:  
| search_str     |  
| pierce brosnan |  
| matt leblank   |  
| jeff goldblum  |
```

3.Table after one of the steps along with examples like:

```
Given I visit <site> 
| site           |  
| google.com     |  
| jeeves.com     |  
| duckduckgo.com |  
When I enter <search_str>  
Then I see at least 1 result  
Examples:  
| search_str     |  
| pierce brosnan |  
| matt leblank   |  
| jeff goldblum  |
```

Comment: Someone please feel free to fix my code formatting... First time writing an answer on SO ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: u must guess it's gonna be me haha

Comment: all i actually did was remove ONE space between list number and description which stopped it being a "numbered list" format and _that_ is what was preventing code view style format.

Comment: Haha, of course @MichaelDurrant :)
I thought I was putting in the spacing mostly correctly, but I didn't know about a small mistake like that would be the root of the issue. Thanks!